# Capturing http data packets on chrome as long as browser active

Tags: http, google-chrome-extension, packet-capture

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension which will capture http packets, their source and destination URLS, the packet size.
Basically I want to know how much time the user spends on a particular site for the duration the browser is active.

I used JNetPcap and successfully have written a java code for the same but i cant find a way to implement the browser close event in Java.
Also chrome extensions need to be in javascript.
Can anyone suggest a way to go about this?

Comment: Edit:

I want to find out the per site data usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach is flawed to begin with. What do you mean by "time spent on a site"? The page loads, packets cease to flow, yet the user is still reading the page. Just network analysis is hardly a good metric.

And what about external resources? Do your users "spend time" on Google Analytics website when trackers make their requests?

If you are dead-set on network capture, [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) or [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) APIs should let you tap into requests made by the client.

---

As for implementing this properly as a Chrome extension, it should be trivial. You can use [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) to keep track of open/active tabs.

1. Declare `"tabs"` permission to get access to URL data
2. On initialization, query current tabs (or just the active tab)
3. Listen to `onCreated` for new tabs, or better yet for `onActivated` for change of visible tab (possibly do so with windows too, there's a separate API for that)
4. Within the active tab, track URL changes with `onUpdated`

If you're new to extension development, start with the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). Good read, and a good hub to other documentation.

As for recommending JavaScript resources, I'll pass; too many of them.

Comment: Ill try and rephrase it.
By "time spent" i mean, the data usage the website makes. I guess there's a problem in the question.